# when user click back button in browser data get retrieved from cache

Tags: php, jsp, caching, time

I want to do something like this when the form in login.jsp is submitted, loginAction.jsp first compares the value from this field against the lastLogon field's value in the User database table. Only when the lastLogon value from the form is greater than the value in the database will it be considered a valid login.  For valid login, the field lastLogon in the database should be updated with the form's value to update the lastLogon's time. When the browsers resubmit from the cache as in the case above, the form's lastLogon value is not greater than the database's lastLogon value, therefore loginAction.jsp forwards the control flow back to login.jsp with an error message stating "Session has ended. Please log in.".

but what if someone alter System time then value retrieve from **System.currentTimeMillis()** will change and none of what i have stated will occur. instead of that user will be able to retrieve copy of data from cache which i don't know. I want to know if system time is altered then anything like i have stated above will occur or not.

If something like what i have stated above happens when one alter's system time will the same will happen if i use **System.nanoTime();**

**THANKS IN ADVANCE.**

Comment: This is too abstract. Please show some code of what you've got now to make this easier to understand.

Comment: but as to `System.currentTimeMillis()` if we're talking about a web application where you're running `System.currentTimeMillis()` on the server then only the server administrator should be able to change the server time not a random user accessing the webpage, unless they're some great hacker.